# Getting html as response when posting form using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, post, symfony4

My mistake should be easy to spot by a more experienced developer so here's hoping you can help me out.

I have a form created in a controller method:

```
public function manage_groups(
    Request $request,
    Globals $globals,
    $_locale,
    $_id
) {
    // manage group logic omitted
    // ...
    $newPhoto = new Photo();
    $photoForm = $this->createForm(PhotoType::class, $newPhoto, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin_upload_foto'),
        'method' => 'POST'
    ));
    // ...

    return $this->render('admin/groups/manage_groups.html.twig', array(            
        'photoform'             => $photoForm->createView()
        // ...
    ));
}
```

The action url points to this controller method:

```
/**
 * Matches /admin/upload/foto
 * @Route(
 *     "/upload/foto",
 *     name="admin_upload_foto")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function upload_photo(
    Request $request
) {
    $response = new JsonResponse();

    $newPhoto = new Fotos();
    $photoForm = $this->createForm(PhotoType::class, $newPhoto);
    $photoForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($photoForm->isSubmitted() && $photoForm->isValid()) {
        // $file stores the uploaded PDF file
        $file = $newPhoto->getFile();

        // Generate a unique name for the file before saving it
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
        // Move the file to the directory where activity photos are stored
        $file->move(
            $this->getParameter('activity_photo_directory'),
            $fileName
        );

        // Update the 'brochure' property to store the PDF file name
        // instead of its contents
        $newPhoto->setFile($this->getParameter('activity_photo_reletive_directory')."/".$fileName);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($newPhoto);
        $em->flush();
        $response->setStatusCode(200);
        $response->setContent(array("result" => 1, "newPhoto" => $newPhoto->getFile(), "category" => $newPhoto->getCategorie()));
    } else if ($photoForm->isSubmitted()) {
        $errors = array();
        $errors[] = $photoForm['categorie']->getErrors();
        $errors[] = $photoForm['file']->getErrors();
        $response->setStatusCode(400);
        $response->setContent(array("result" => 0, "errors" => $errors));
    } else {
        $response->setStatusCode(400);
        $response->setContent(array("result" => 0, "errors" => "Het foto-formulier is niet verzonden naar de server"));
    }
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return $response;
}
```

The page loads correctly and the form can be submitted using the following ajax:

```
    dialogUploadPhoto.find('form').submit((event) => {
        // const formData = new FormData();
        // formData.append('photo-file', dialogUploadPhoto.find('input[type="file"]')[0].files[0]);
        // formData.append('photo-categorie', $('photo-categorie').val());
        const formData = new FormData(this);
        // formData.append('photo-categorie', dialogUploadPhoto.find('photo-categorie').val());
        // formData.append('photo-file', dialogUploadPhoto.find('input[type="file"]')[0].files[0]);
        console.log(' >> >> >> Uploading image', formData);
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(), // formData,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(' >> >> Upload successful: ', response);

                dialogSelectPhoto.find("div:first-child").prepend(
                    '<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" ' +
                    'onclick="handleImageClick(\''+response.newPhoto+'\');">' +
                    '<img src="'+window.location.origin+'/'+response.newPhoto+'" width="250" height="auto" />' +
                    '</a>');

                dialogUploadPhoto.dialog( "close" );
            },
            error: function (xhr, desc, err){
                let errors = 'Unknown error occurred';
                if (xhr.responseJSON.errors instanceof Array) {
                    errors = "<ul>";
                    if (xhr.responseJSON.errors[0]) {
                        errors += "<li>Categorie: " + xhr.responseJSON.errors[0] + "</li>";
                    }
                    if (xhr.responseJSON.errors[1]) {
                        errors += "<li>Foto: " + xhr.responseJSON.errors[1] + "</li>";
                    }
                    errors += "</ul>";
                } else {
                    errors = xhr.responseJSON.errors;
                }
                dialogUploadPhotoError.find("#dialogUploadPhotoErrorMessage").html(errors);
                dialogUploadPhotoError.dialog('open');
            }
        });
    });
```

I've tried a couple of things, the ajax returns a success with the page in plain html but the controller method isn't called (breakpoint not hit)

**As requested**
Here is a screenshot of the tcp package response
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Please add screen shoots

Comment: What is the exact response from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but it looks like your ajax call goes to your function `manage_groups()` .

In your ajax call :

```
url: $(this).attr('action'),
```

It looks like your form comes from your manage_groups() function, so your call goes inside this function.

Try this :

```
 url: "/upload/foto"
```

Hope it will works

Comment: I already checked that. `$(this).attr('action')` resolves to `/admin/upload/foto`. Don't think it's related. I'll type it manually to be sure

Comment: Your answer got me to notice something. my ajax success function was an arrow function. That means $(this) didn't refer to the form!

Comment: i'm glad you figured it out !

Comment: Looking back at it; it was pretty stupid. Then again, it mostly is. Thanks anyways